# Are AWS S3 Event Notifications guaranteed to be delivered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm hooking up AWS S3 event notifications to an AWS Lambda processing pipeline.

I can't find documentation on S3 event notification guarantees.  Can I be sure all S3 events will fire the lambda processes?  Order does not concern me, just that my lambda eventually does get fired.

If no such guarantee exists, how to architect to deal with this?

Comment: As long as you defined at s3 that your bucket sends the events, don't see any reason to suspect it wouldn't...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 2020**

The events are now at least once: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

Relevant quote from that page:

> Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer.

**Original answer**

In principle yes. However, Lambda has a 99.9% SLA and S3 has a 99.9% uptime SLA as well. So in theory some events could be missed, but only when they have a service disruption. When the Lambda function fails, it automatically retries up to three times.

I use S3 as a 'queue' for Lambda and have never missed a message (out of millions and millions).

There's not much you can do to deal with this I think. Part of using 'serverless' infrastructure means that you also lose some control (however, I think that AWS can do a better job than just myself and a few dedicated servers).

Comment: 2.5 years later is this still working out well for you? I am considering using S3 in the same way.

Comment: Yes we still use this on our live environment and have processed many billions of events successfully this way!

Comment: Lambda will retry an async invocation twice, not three times.

Comment: I think you mean "in principle no, but in practice yes". A 'guarantee' is a formal assurance or promise regarding something. In practice, you may never actually have an issue because the provider makes all reasonable efforts to ensure that things happen they way they're supposed to, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html *"[...] On very rare occasions, events might be lost. [...]"* Have you not encountered this yet? We are thinking about implementing some mitigation if this is actually a true statement.

Comment: Hard to say. If they get lost you probably also don't see an error popping up as nothing is triggered. But we still run those pipelines (so around 3.5 years since my answer), have processed billions and billions of lambda executions and never encountered an issue which could be tied back to this.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite interesting that AWS has upgraded semantic from **at most once** to **at least once** just by documentation, not the product.

Before 2020, it's something like below per this [link](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/aws-s3-event-notifications-probably-once.html):

> Amazon S3 event notifications typically deliver events in seconds but
> can sometimes take a minute or longer. On very rare occasions, events
> might be lost. If your application requires particular semantics (for
> example, ensuring that no events are missed, or that operations run
> only once), we recommend that you account for missed and duplicate
> events when designing your application. You can audit for missed
> events by using the LIST Objects API or Amazon S3 Inventory reports.
> The LIST Objects API and Amazon S3 inventory reports are subject to
> eventual consistency and might not reflect recently added or deleted
> objects.

In 2020, it's changed to **at least once**, as below:

> Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer.

In Nov 2021, it's downgraded again to **only once**, per this [PR](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-userguide/commit/0bd3dc39ac8431ede9b48cbc7c0759f37bcf96ee#diff-f5bf47daa36cdc9c5771329bc0f80c1bb481c662615f8ed4d5cea90e06cda3ddL6).

> By default, Amazon S3 event notifications are delivered only once. Most of the time, event notifications are delivered in seconds. However, sometimes it can take a minute or longer for them to be delivered.

In Dec 2021, we pointed out that AWS made a backward incompatible change, AWS explained it was an incident of the document change, though I don't believe it. So AWS soon changed the document back to as below:

> Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once. Typically, event notifications are delivered in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer

But AWS support also told us, that it's designed to be at least once, but does not guarantee anything.

So it's not only confusing, but also misleading.

Comment: well, AWS support told us that S3 event notification is designed to be delivered AT LEAST ONCE, but does NOT guarantee your lambda is invoked.

How confusing is it!

Comment: so, you should not depend on this or you need to implement scheduled lambda, which will process files for which you did not receive any event....

Comment: @YoujunYuan the S3 service is limited to guaranteeing to successfully send the event to the lambda service (i.e. via asynchronous invoke), at which point the event is "owned" by the Lambda infrastructure and the S3 team no longer has any control to guarantee anything.  You could adversarially set the concurrency to 0 and have a "no retries" policy in which case you're guaranteed your function is never invoked (but the DLQ will be populated).

The Lambda team still guarantees that it will invoke your Lambda according to your configuration, by default 6 hours, retrying another two times.

Answer (score 2):

[From the Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)
**Important**
Amazon S3 event notifications typically deliver events in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer. **On very rare occasions, events might be lost**.

We are seeing lost events right now. A lot in volume but low by percentage.

Comment: Related to the link provided, look here to decide which error handling logic to implement: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html

Comment: note that the doc was updated and now it states guaranteed delivery

Comment: @mishka thanks for that update. That's certainly interesting

Comment: It doesn't say, and never has said, "guaranteed delivery". It says "Amazon S3 event notifications are designed to be delivered at least once." Designed to do X and guaranteed to do X are not the same thing. While you may never see an incident of event loss (because the system is designed to prevent it) it's not a guarantee.

Comment: @jarmod it now explicitly state the edge case where an event can be lost: "If two writes are made to a single non-versioned object at the same time, it is possible that only a single event notification will be sent."

Comment: This article will clear lot of your doubts you have. https://singlequote.blog/listing-billion-number-of-s3-objects-into-sqs-challenges-benchmarks/