# SLA for S3 event triggered message delivery to SQS via SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an AWS setup where an S3 bucket is setup with an SNS event to trigger a notification on `putObject` which is expected to push a message to it's subscribed SQS queue.
I wanted to gather information regarding the SLA that AWS guarantees for the S3-SNS event trigger and subsequently SNS-SQS message push delivery. I am interested in two independent numbers :
1. SLA for SNS notification trigger upon S3 event.
2. SLA for SNS to SQS message delivery.

I read about the message delivery guarantee in AWS FAQs but could not find any information regarding the SLA it guarantees, if any.

Comment: Duplicate ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238446/are-aws-s3-event-notifications-guaranteed-to-be-delivered

Comment: @JamesDean Not only am I not asking about the guarantee (I'm asking about the SLA) but also the question mentioned talks about only half the scope of my question.

Comment: @iammrmehul It is rare that AWS has an SLA, and they generally cover system availability rather than minor features of a service. Do you have a reference to this "SLA"? Can you point us to this "message delivery guarantee"?

Comment: https://singlequote.blog/listing-billion-number-of-s3-objects-into-sqs-challenges-benchmarks/ This article provides the details if you want to utilize the SQS and S3 and also provides details around message delivery.