# Why SQS is better than S3 for Event based scenario

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have to design a cost optimized solution which should be aws cloud native .
The problem that i have to solve is i have 90 millions messages coming from data base.
Every event is independent and no ordering is required in order to process that .
I have to process every messages and do some operation and then put that into Elastic search service .

The solution for this that i have thought is below one

```
AWS API-->LAMBDA-->SNS-->SQS(1)-->LAMBDA-->ES
                     --->SQS(2)-->LAMBDA-->ES
```

Basically from SNS is used so that multiple SQS can consume at the same time .

While doing this i thought why cant we use S3 so that record can be persisted for ever and can be replicated into another region,Also we can invoke lambda function on every put event in S3 .

So my plan is if we use S3 then for 90 millions records we will be creating 90 millions files into s3 and then using cloud front we can read or even without cloud from we can read from s3 using lambda function .

```
API-->S3-->lambda--->ES
```

The throughput of S3 put is 3500/second/folder and out through out is 5000/sec/prefix .
The cost of put request in s3 and sqs is almost same .

Can someone tell me what is wrong is using S3 based solution .
I know using SQS looks very obvious here but what is the risk if we use S3 int this case ?

The through put out that i am looking for is 5k per second .

Even the cost wise SQS one looks costlier because i need to pay fro SNS +SQS both but if we use S3 only S3 put and lambda

Please suggest

Comment: Also worth understanding the guarantees around delivery for S3 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238446/are-aws-s3-event-notifications-guaranteed-to-be-delivered) vs. SNS (https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/).

Comment: @jarmod so s3 also looks promising in this case ?

Comment: Maybe prototype a couple of options. You likely have requirements outside of what you've mentioned above so providing a best architecture via Stack Overflow questions is  not ideal. The S3 approach provides excellent long-term durability for messages (if you need that) and is low cost, but an SNS/SQS approach would likely be preferable at very high scale (higher ingest rates and lower latency read/write than S3), though triggering Lambda with a push model could cause scaling issues with whatever Lambda does (e.g. write to a backend DB). You should also consider Kinesis Data Streams.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do either of those, and do this:

```
API --> SNS --> Lambda --> ES
            --> Lambda --> ES
```

SNS to lambda will run as many lambdas as are necessary to handle the request load, up to the limits on your account, or the limits set on the lambda. The only reason to put SQS in there is for some added resiliency, but I'd probably just do that on the Lambda, as a dead letter queue.

Comment: But what the guarantee that message will not be lost ..Also Why not s3 approach ..I feel your approach is even better .But why should we rule out S3 here .

Comment: Very unlikely the message wouldn't be delivered [Message Delivery Retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html). The S3 approach would work, assuming you didn't hit rate limits, but it's not really the ideal approach for this, and it will be slower.

Comment: SNS starts throttling after 1000 concurrent request because of lambda limit and it straight way starts going into DLQ so putting SQS handles that ...

Comment: SNS will send batches of records to lambda, not just one at a time. If you believe you need a higher limit then you can get an increase (the 1000 is a soft limit).