# Can S3 event notifications get missing when changing notification configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to update s3 bucket configuration so object created events start to flow into another SQS queue. The question is, after I applied the new configuration is there a possibility that some notifications will be missing in the time window between the times when the change is applied and when it actually starts to be active (starts to send notifications into the new SQS queue).

Comment: It's a distributed system and I see no formal documentation of any consistency guarantees here, but I would presume that the events will go to the old queue or the new queue because there won't be a point in time where there is no queue configured.

Comment: Why do you assume there is a time *between* the two configs? As soon as the new config is there it is active. Chances are you do not exactly know ***when*** it is distributed to everywhere and becomes active but there should be no time when neither the old nor the new config is active. And questions about details *this* intricate are best directed at the AWS support because you can be pretty sure there is no official doc for this and best thing you can hope for is people like me telling you their expectations / experiences but no hard proof.

Comment: @jarmod That's my intuition as well, but I wanted a "hard proof", maybe a link to some documentation, or an answer from a knowledgeable AWS engineer. Since it is quite critical to catch all the notifications in the system I am working with.

Comment: @luk2302 I agree that it probably works the way you explain. Actually checking with support sounds like a good idea, thank you.

Comment: You may also need to understand the underlying event guarantees too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238446/are-aws-s3-event-notifications-guaranteed-to-be-delivered).